# Last value of char array unknown - C

Tags: c, arrays, char, overflow

I'm making a simple program in C, which checks the length of some char array and if it's less than 8, I want to fill a new array with zeroes and add it to the former array. Here comes the problem. I don't know why the last values are some signs(see the photo).

```
char* hexadecimalno = decToHex(decimal,hexadecimal);
printf("Hexadecimal: %s\n", hexadecimalno);
char zeroes [8 - strlen(hexadecimalno)];
if(strlen(hexadecimalno) < 8){
    for(i = 0; i < (8-strlen(hexadecimalno)); i++){
        zeroes[i]='0';
    }
}
printf("zeroes: %s\n",zeroes);
strcat(zeroes,hexadecimalno);
printf("zeroes: %s\n",zeroes);
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNbxI.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, strings (which are, as you are aware, arrays of characters) do not have any special metadata that tells you their length. Instead, the convention is that the string stops at the first character whose `char` value is `0`. This is called "null-termination". The way your code is initializing `zeroes` does not put any null character at the end of the array. (Do not confuse the `'0'` characters you are putting in with NUL characters -- they have `char` value `48`, not `0`.)

All of the string manipulation functions assume this convention, so when you call `strcat`, it is looking for that `0` character to decide the point at which to start adding the hexadecimal values.

C also does not automatically allocate memory for you. It assumes you know exactly what you are doing. So, your code is using a C99 feature to dynamically allocate an array `zeroes` that has exactly the number of elements as you need `'0'` characters appended. You *aren't* allocating an extra byte for a terminating NUL character, and `strcat` is also going to assume that you have allocated space for the contents of `hexadecimalno`, which you have not. In C, this does not trigger a bounds check error. It just writes over memory that you shouldn't actually write over. So, you need to be very careful that you *do* allocate enough memory, and that you only write to memory you have actually allocated.

In this case, you want `hexadecimalno` to always be 8 digits long, left-padding it with zeroes. That means you need an array with 8 `char` values, plus one for the NUL terminator. So, `zeroes` needs to be a `char[9]`.

After your loop that sets `zeroes[i] = '0'` for the correct number of zeroes, you need to set the *next* element to `char` value `0`. The fact that you are zero-padding confuses things, but again, remember that `'0'` and `0` are two different things.

Provided you allocate enough space (at least 9 characters, assuming that `hexadecimalno` will never be longer than 8 characters), and then that you null terminate the array when putting the zeroes into it for padding, you should get the expected result.